# How to launch an Activity in different task stack?

Tags: android

I have seen some app able to launch Activity in different task stack.

The Activity launched from app icon and the Activity launched from home widget, will both re-inside different task stack.

Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

---

I try to achieve the same behavior. In my home widget code, whenever I want to launch Activity, I will use the following flag.

```java
Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeWidgetLauncherFragmentActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

However, I fail to achieve the same behavior as above screenshot. There are always only 1 task stack for my app.

Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same [taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#aff), as mentioned here

> The task that the activity has an affinity for. Activities with the
>   same affinity conceptually belong to the same task (to the same
>   "application" from the user's perspective). The affinity of a task is
>   determined by the affinity of its root activity.

so with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` you need to provide an affinity to create a different task stack using

```
    <activity
        android:taskAffinity="com.example.widget"
        android:name=".WidgetActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_widget"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

> The affinity determines two things — the task that the activity is
>   re-parented to (see the allowTaskReparenting attribute) and the task
>   that will house the activity when it is launched with the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

Default affinity string value is the package name attribute in manifest.

> If this attribute is not set, the activity inherits the affinity set
>   for the application (see the  element's taskAffinity
>   attribute). The name of the default affinity for an application is the
>   package name set by the  element.